# Response to HTTP request at production mode in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I run rails server in production environment by `rails server -e production`, rails runs as a single-threaded application.

So will it respond to one HTTP request at a time or more requests at a time?

Comment: of course multiple request at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is single-threaded so one request can only enter the action after the previous requests finish. But it can respond to multiple requests at a time.

Answer (score 2):

It depend on which server you are using to run rails application .

For instance if you are using Webrick server (which is single threaded by default)then you will handle one request at a time but if you use passenger server then it will create instances of your application (which is configurable), then you can handle multiple request at a time